# Calling controller method from a helper module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, fragment-caching

Using Rails 3.2

I'm trying to call `expire_fragment`, the Rails view method, from a helper but getting an error:

```
undefined method `expire_fragment' for #<#<Class:0x00000118977110>:0x00000103b853b8>
```

I'm trying to conditionally clear the cache.  This is the helper method call in my view

```
clear_cache_keys_if(params[:cc], [@product, :search_filters])
```

And in the helper

```
  def clear_cache_keys_if(condition, keys = [])
    if condition
      keys.each do |key|
        expire_fragment(key)
      end
    end
  end
```

I would have thought that the Rails fragment caching methods would be accessible in a helper module, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I changed it to

```
controller.expire_fragment(key)
```

And that worked.

This method is available in the view.  It's available from the controller.  I don't really understand why it is not available in a helper.  What am I missing here?  Why isn't it available in the helper and what is the best way to expose it?  Thanks

Comment: Helpers are available in the controller and view templates by default.  You have to include them in the helper class you wish to use them in.  Try adding `include ActionView::Helpers` to your helper class.

Comment: Actually, post-Rails 3, It's `ActionController::Base.helpers`